# About decompositions of induced characters

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

> Suppose $G$ is a finite group, $H\leqslant G$ is a subgroup. $\chi_1,...,\chi_s$ are all the irreducible characters of $G$ and $\psi$ is an irreducible character of $H$. Prove that if $$\psi\uparrow G=d_1\chi_1+...+d_s\chi_s$$ $d_1,...,d_s$ are no-negative integers. Then$$d_1^2+...+d_s^2\leq[G:H]$$

This is a homework problem after learning the induced characters and Frobenius Reciprocity theorem. It occurred to me there is a similar result concerning restrictions of characters.

> Suppose $G$ is a finite group, $H\leqslant G$ is a subgroup. $\psi_1,...,\psi_s$ are all the irreducible characters of $H$ and $\chi$ is an irreducible character of $G$. If $$\chi\downarrow H=d_1\psi_1+...+d_s\psi_s$$ $d_1,...,d_s$ are no-negative integers. Then$$d_1^2+...+d_s^2\leq[G:H]$$

But I didn't get any message useful from that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\psi \in Irr(H)$ and assume that $\psi^G=\sum_{i=1}^sd_i\chi_i$, where $\chi_i \in Irr(G)$ and $d_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. Since the irreducible characters form an orthonormal basis, it follows that the inner product $[\psi^G,\psi^G]=\sum_{i=1}^sd_i^2:=m$. By Frobenius Reciprocity, $[\psi^G,\psi^G]=[(\psi^G)_H,\psi]$. So $(\psi^G)_H=m\psi + \Delta$, where $\Delta$ is a character of $H$ or $\Delta \equiv 0$. Hence $(\psi^G)_H(1)=\psi(1)|G:H| \geq m\psi(1)$, and so $m \leq |G:H|$.

Conversely, assume $\chi_H=\sum_{j=1}^te_j\psi_j$, where $\psi_j \in Irr(H)$ and $e_j \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. It follows that $[\chi_H,\chi_H]=\sum_{j=1}^te_j^2:=n$. But $[\chi_H,\chi_H]=[(\chi_H)^G,\chi]$, so $(\chi_H)^G=n\chi + \Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a character of $G$ or $\Gamma \equiv 0$. Hence $(\chi_H)^G(1)=\chi(1)|G:H| \geq n\chi(1)$, and so $n \leq |G:H|$.